# Do I need to remove or delete HTML elements that I created but didn't attach to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvg

I'm implementing client side download of some (High)charts that I have. What I'm doing now is getting the SVG source of the charts, creating a "canvas" element & drawing the SVG to said element, and then downloading the image using toBlob/Filesaver.js. See code below:

```
// draw the svg to a canvas
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
canvg(c, file);

// scrape the image from the canvas as png or jpg and download it in full quality
c.toBlob(function (blob) {
  saveAs(blob, fileName);
}, contentType, 1);
```

Right now the download works fine as expected, but it seems that the canvas element I created, `c`, has been attached to the window and sticks around even after the download finishes.

Calling `c.remove()` doesn't help. `c.parentNode` and `c.parentElement` are null (obviously since I haven't attached `c` to the DOM) so I can't call `removeChild(c)` on anything.

I'm wondering how can I remove/delete element `c`? Is `c = undefined/null` good enough? Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once `c` goes out of scope, it *should* get garbage collected automatically, so as long as `canvg` doesn't keep an unnecessary reference to it.

To ensure `c` eventually becomes not referenceable anymore, put the whole code in an IIFE:

```
(() => {
  // draw the svg to a canvas
  var c = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvg(c, file);

  // scrape the image from the canvas as png or jpg and download it in full quality
  c.toBlob(function (blob) {
    saveAs(blob, fileName);
  }, contentType, 1);
})();
```

(otherwise, it'll stick around as `window.c`)

Comment: This did the trick!

I agree that `c` should have been garbage collected as long as canvg is not keeping a reference. But why would putting the logic inside an IIFE prevent that unnecessary reference?

Comment: @nal88 Because variables initialized with `var` on the top level (eg inside a `<script>` directly) get assigned to the global object. Variables *not* on the top level do not get assigned to the global object, which is why the IIFE works - `c` is not declared on the top level that way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes previous answer is right but you can also clear canvas, by setting the smallest size of it

```
(() => {
     var c = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvg(c, file);
      c.toBlob(function (blob) {
              saveAs(blob, fileName);
              c.width = c.height = 0;
      }, contentType, 1); 
})()
```

Comment: Is there an added benefit to clearing the canvas before letting the garbage collector remove it?

Comment: Smallest size is 0. Setting the size of a canvas which has an active context does trigger a lot of garbage (basically a new context  + a new baking buffer). The GC will only kick when it will have to anyway. You won't win anything by doing this, quite the contrary.

Comment: @Kaiido if i will draw a white rectangle on it?) GC just will remove from memory after some time, and while it not be removed this canvas will be less sized

Comment: White is 255,255,255,255 => the worse in terms of raw size... and once again, changing the size of your canvas just creates new trashes that should get collected too. Just leave the canvas as it is, makes sure no reference holds and let the browser do its job.